# Node.js Authentication library with "persistence token" functionality

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication

I have a working knowledge of [passport for node](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport), but it doesn't have things such as:

- generating a "persistence token" (such as in [authlogic/session/session.rb#L35](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/b91683d71fbeb5c9dabe1b675982b03792ac4a20/lib/authlogic/session/session.rb#L35)
- generating perishable tokens for password resets
- remember me functionality
- managing those properties for login/logout on some model class, etc.

Are there any libraries that have solved this in the Node.js community? If there is anything as robust (or on it's way to being as robust) as [Devise for Rails](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), that would be perfect, but anything that solves this token issue will work just as well.

The crazy thing is a lot of the examples out there are storing the user `id` in the session!

```
request.session['userId'] = user.get('id')
```

That is just asking to be hacked.

It should be something like this:

```
require.session['persistenceToken'] = App.User.generateRandomToken()
```

Comment: I guess it's not that hard to implement, just wish it already existed.

Comment: I've put together a "remember me" strategy: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-remember-me

Answer (score 8):

A one-time password (aka single-use token) strategy for password resets is something that I'll be implementing.  Given Passport's architecture, this can easily be a separate module and it wouldn't surprise me to find out someone else has already implemented such a thing.

Remember me and persistence token functionality is also something I'd like to support.  Preferably, I'd like that to be a separate strategy as well, but it may need some core support.  If that turns out to be the case, a few extra lines in `req.logIn` ( https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/passport/http/request.js#L28 ) should be able to cover it.

As for storing a user ID in the session, I don't see any big risk given that, by default in Connect/Express, session properties are stored entirely in the backend and looked up by a unique `sid` that is set in an encrypted cookie.  A malicious user would have to possess both the unique sid and session secret in order to spoof requests.

Mozilla is using Passport as part of their identity effort, to bridge BrowserID to other providers which lack BrowserID support (see [browserid-bigtent](https://github.com/mozilla/browserid-bigtent)).  Given their requirements, developers can be sure that Passport meets strict security requirements.

(Ultimately session serialization in Passport is an application's responsibility, so a random token in place of a user ID can be used if desired for security reasons.  Obviously this should be done if storing data directly in the cookie, but I'd suggest that doing that is the most ill-advised approach.)

As far as managing those properties on a model, Passport is designed to be completely model/ORM agnostic.  I don't intend to ever change that fact, as I think those decisions are best left to the application (and Passport is more flexible as a result of delegating this responsiblity).  That said, I think there is room for other modules to independently build on top of Passport to provide this functionality.

All that said, I think Passport is the most robust of the existing Node.js auth solutions.  Your first three requests would go a long way to making it more so, and they should be easy to accomplish.  I'd love to collaborate on getting these features in, so don't hesitate to get in contact with me.

Finally, in case anyone is curious, first-class API authentication is presently in the works, on the [authinfo](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/tree/authinfo) branch.  Building on this, [passport-http-oauth](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http-oauth) implements OAuth server strategies, which can be combined with [oauthorize](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauthorize) middlware as a toolkit to assemble OAuth servers.  This isn't fully baked yet, but it'll be another effective feature of Passport when its ready.

Comment: I am using passport with local authentication strategy and would love to add the Remember Me functionaility. Can I somehow set the cookie lifetime in my serializeUser() function ro do I have to hack the core? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

In the meanwhile, something like the following should be sufficient. Adjust as necessary to fit your app and desired cookie duration. Checking for username & password is a kind of cheesy way to detect a login attempt, but it works well enough with passport.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if(
            typeof(req.body.username) !== "undefined"
            && typeof(req.body.password) !== "undefined"
            ) {
        if(req.body.remember == 1) {
            req.session.cookie.maxAge = 365*24*60*60*1000;
        }
        else {
            req.session.cookie.maxAge = 24*60*60*1000;
        }
    }
    next();
});
```

Comment: I wonder why setting `res.session.cookie.maxAge = null;` inside the `else` statement won't work? I tried it, and if I log in once with the "Remember Me" option set to true, then all subsequent logins will also have a persistent cookie set, even if "Remember Me" is off.

Comment: I just realized that I should've used `req.session.cookie.expires = false` instead, I will post an alternate answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

While I would definitely like to see these features in passport.js, they are not there yet.

I have created a simple random token generator to use with passport.js serilizeUser() function, and modified Justen's answer just a bit to suit my needs. Basically, the only difference is that if the "remember" option is not set, the session will last as long as the browser is open.

This is my serializer with the random access token generator. I am using Mongodb and Mongoose, but the implementation should translate to other systems quite well.

Basically, I am getting the time and appending a random 16-character string to it. Then, in the serializeUser() function I check that no other user has the same token (the token should be unique!).

```
User.methods.generateRandomToken = function () {
  var user = this,
      chars = "_!abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890",
      token = new Date().getTime() + '_';
  for ( var x = 0; x < 16; x++ ) {
    var i = Math.floor( Math.random() * 62 );
    token += chars.charAt( i );
  }
  return token;
};
```

Here's the serializer:

```
passport.serializeUser( function ( user, done ) {

  var createAccessToken = function () {
    var token = user.generateRandomToken();
    app.User.findOne( { accessToken: token }, function (err, existingUser) {
      if (err) return done( err );
      if (existingUser)
        createAccessToken(); // Run the function again - the token has to be unique!
      else {
        user.set( 'accessToken', token );
        user.save( function ( err ) {
          if (err) return done( err );
          return done( null, user.get('accessToken') );
        })
      }
    });
  };

  if ( user._id ) {
    createAccessToken();
  }
});
```

...and here is my version of the middleware that handles the "remember me" functionality. I would much rather this somehow be part of the serializeUser function or passport.js core, though.

```
app.use( express.session( { secret: 'secret_key' } ) );
app.use( function (req, res, next) {
    if ( req.method == 'POST' && req.url == '/login' ) {
      if ( req.body.remember ) {
        req.session.cookie.maxAge = 30*24*60*60*1000; // Rememeber 'me' for 30 days
      } else {
        req.session.cookie.expires = false;
      }
    }
    next();
});
app.use( passport.initialize() );
app.use( passport.session() );
```

I hope that helps somehow. It took me couple of hours to figure it out and I am not quite sure this is the *best* way to do it but it works for me, for now.

Comment: I know this is really old, but how is using the session middleware helpful here? Can we not just skip it?